# apache serve files based on domain name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, httpd.conf

Lets say, i have 3 domain names

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

All @ records currently go to my server, resolving to `root/index.php`.
Currently, i redirect each domain to different sub-folders with header redirects within index.php. So each url looks like

`http://domain1.com/new_root1/index.php`
`http://domain2.com/new_root2/index.php`
`http://domain3.com/new_root3/index.php`
Not very pretty.. but it works.

I am trying to configure my server to redirect with `httpd.conf`. What i would like is have domain1 and domain2 resolve:
 `http://domain[*].com/index.php`
on local ip `192.168.0.101:80`
and domain3 resolve:
`http://domain3.com/index.php`on local ip `192.168.0.100:1979`
There is plenty of documentation, tutorials,etc, but nothing seems to fit this..
I have looked at .htacess. Preferred comments are to use `httpd.conf`. Searched Apache docs.
 All attempts fail.
Where do i look? Tx in advance

Comment: You should configure virtual hosts in your Apache settings.

Comment: @Raptor correct. This is what i am attempting.  Tried several configurations, all domains still resolve to /root/. and there is still the issue of serving domain3 from another machine, based on it's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic name based vhost configuration all of the domains will use port 80 and work as expected. You can set httpd.conf to load all individual .conf files in a particular folder and then add individual .conf files to that folder, each containing 1 vhost definition.

Near the bottom of my apache2.conf I added:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# Include all my projects vhost conf files:
Include /vagrant/vhosts/*.conf
```

And in the folder I specified for loading my project vhost conf files I add a bunch of .conf files that look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.demo.vm
ServerAlias demo.vm

DocumentRoot /vagrant/htdocs/demo.vm/public

<Directory /vagrant/htdocs/demo.vm/public>
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

</VirtualHost>
```

If this is a local server you would have to edit your operating system hosts file to point your custom domain to the localhost.

Comment: This did the trick, with some tweaking. Wasn't sure what `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"` meant, so i omitted it first try. Worked out of the box. Ty.

Comment: SetEnv would make $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] available in your php code. You could have code behave one way when running on your localhost server and another when when running on your live server (displaying a bunch of debug info below the site footer when running locally for example)

Comment: Very well explained. TYVM for your time :)